# Canvas ratio size

Tags: wpf

I have a selfcreated usercontrol that inherits from canvas. 
Now it is nessesary that this canvas object has always a ratio between width and height.
How is this possible?
I tried this one but it does not work:

```
        private void Canvas_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        Vector vec = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(this);
        if(e.WidthChanged)
            Arrange(new Rect(vec.X, vec.Y, ActualWidth, Image.Height / Image.Width * this.ActualWidth));
        else if(e.HeightChanged)
            Arrange(new Rect(vec.X, vec.Y, Image.Width / Image.Height * this.ActualHeight, ActualHeight));

    }
```

Now i would like to ask if you have any ideas. The ratio is Image.Height/Image.Width (Image is the background image of the canvas object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override [ArrangeOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.arrangeoverride.aspx):

```
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
{
    Size size = base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);
    double aspectRatio = ...

    return new Size(size.Width, size.Width / aspectRatio);

    // or, if Height determines the final size
    // return new Size(size.Height * aspectRatio, size.Height);
}
```

And you have to make sure that the Canvas' parent does not set its `Width` or `Height` at the same time.

You could for example put it inside another Canvas and set either your Canvas' `Width` or `Height` explicitely. Or you put it in a Grid and set proper values for `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment`.

Comment: thanks a lot this is exactly what i need. so i would guess this is one of the best programming communities